# SSH parameterized config entries?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I often setup port forwards with something like:
`ssh -NL 1234:localhost:1234 MyHostName`

The ports usually stay the same, but the remote changes. It would be nice if I could create SSH entries like:

```
Host VncTunnel
  HostName %arg
  LocalForward 5900 localhost:5900
```

and then use something like `ssh VncTunnel arg=MyHostName` whenever I want to tunnel to an arbitrary host.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below solution was tested with `ssh` from OpenSSH, version 9.3 (but it should work with reasonably non-ancient older versions as well, I *guess* from 7.2 where [bz#2471](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2471) was fixed). **For 9.4 and later see [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1834777/432690), IMO the solution there is The Right Thing.**

---

Paste this snippet at the beginning of your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Match exec "case $VNCT in ?) exit 0;; esac; exit 1"
  LocalForward 5900 localhost:5900
```

Now if you run `ssh` with non-empty `VNCT` in the environment then `LocalForward 5900 localhost:5900` will be applied. Like this:

```
VNCT=1 ssh -N MyHostName
```

The solution can be expanded. E.g. this *additional* snippet:

```
Match exec "case $PRXY in ?) exit 0;; esac; exit 1"
  LocalForward 8080 localhost:8080
```

will allow you to run `VNCT=1 PRXY=1 ssh -N MyHostName` to enable both forwardings. You can enable each forwarding independently. You can create more snippets.

Notes:

- `case $VNCT in ?) exit 0;; esac; exit 1` is not the simplest way to test if the variable is not empty. In general there are simpler ways, but many of them require double-quoting in the shell code. I haven't found a way to pass `"` inside the double-quoted value to `Match exec`, therefore I decided to use `case` where [double-quoting is not necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618).
- It's about non-empty variable vs empty/unset, so `VNCT=0` will also enable the respective forwarding. If you use `case $VNCT in 1) …` then only `VNCT=1` will enable it, every other value (including `VNCT=0`) will not.
- The solution may even work with scripts and tools that use `ssh` under the hood; or in some cases it may not.

  A tool may run `ssh` in a sanitized environment or with options that interfere, but if it calls `ssh` in the most straightforward way then our config will work, you just need to put the right variable into the environment (e.g. `VNCT=1 tool`). I don't expect you'd want to create tunnels this way, but you are not limited to `LocalForward`, with our method you can impose other configuration options on demand. This will be particularly useful if the tool does not provide any option to customize arguments it passes to `ssh`.

Comment: This works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Credit to Kamil for bringing me to the idea with the Match in the first place, it looks like his answer is the working one if you do not have one of the latest `openssh` versions (which is probable not very common quite yet).

After some research, I found out that new versions of `openssh` have added very recently (around half a year ago) the concept of tags, which makes this solution much simpler, see the documentation at [the ssh-config manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html)

In `~/.ssh/config` now you need this configuration:

```
Match tagged VncTunnel
    LocalForward 5900 localhost:5900
```

and then you can use it when calling `ssh` like this:

```
ssh -P VncTunnel MyHostName
```

It looks the change got introduced in version 9.4 (see [here](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.4)).

Comment: The Match solution is working for me currently but I plan to try this one out soon too; will update the accepted answer if I get this to work.

Answer (score 7):

While the OpenSSH "tags" feature mentioned by 'gepa' is probably the neatest option when available, it's still recent enough that your systems are likely to not have it yet, and in that case my suggestion is to *not do it via `ssh`* in the first place.

You could do the same using a shell script, or a shell function, or a shell alias, without requiring any of the contortions required to achieve it through ssh_config:

- For example, in Bash (`~/.bashrc`):

  ```
  alias vnctun="ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900"

  $ vnctun foo
     → becomes: ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 foo
  ```
- Also in Bash/Zsh using functions (also in `~/.bashrc`):

  ```
  vnctun() { ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 "$@"; }
  ```
- In PowerShell (`notepad $profile`):

  ```
  Function vnctun($Name) { ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 $Name }
  ```
- In Windows Cmd.exe ([AutoRun](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-autoexec.html)):

  ```
  doskey vnctun=ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 $*
  ```
- In any Linux shell, as a standalone script in `~/bin/vnctun` (needs a change to $PATH):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 "$@"
  ```
- In Windows Cmd.exe, but as a standalone script in `vnctun.cmd`:

  ```
  @echo off
  ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 %*
  ```

(You can even extend this to automatically start the VNC client after the connection has been established.)